# Autofac Contrib Multi Tenant throws "Request is not available in this context" exception

Tags: autofac

I am using http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration version 2.4.4 with Autofac 2.4.4 on an ASP.Net MVC 3.0.

I use the new Asp.Net MVC 3 support (using AutofacDependencyResolver). I encounter a problem that the tenant identification strategy class (implementing ITenantIdentificationStrategy) throws "Request is not available in this context" exception.

I tried using  AutofacContrib.Multitenant.Web.RequestParameterTenantIdentificationStrategy class and it also throws the same exception.

My application_start looks as follow

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //wire up all the necessary objects used in this web application
    IContainer container = BootStrap.RegisterAll().Build();

    //multi tenant support
    MultitenantContainer multiTenant = new MultiTenancy().Register(container);


    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(multiTenant.BeginLifetimeScope()));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. HttpContext.Current.Request is not available at Application_Start in IIS 7.0. The only solution to this is to capture the HTTPException and set the TenantId to null at Catch and return false.

```
    public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
    {
        var current = HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                tenantId = null;
                return false;
            }

            var request = current.Request;
        }
        catch (HttpException)
        {
            tenantId = null;
            return false;
        }

        //continue with your tenant identification
    }
```